# InitialContext.lookup gets data from wrong context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have two Tomcat servers running on one machine as Windows services, each is installed in diffrent HD and uses diffrent ports.
Each Tomcat holds Datasource refrence in it's context.xml to JDBC driver (both connctions are to the same MySql server, but diffrent DB) :

Tomcat1:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/monitor" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100"
maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="user" password="password"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/monitor
autoReconnect=true&amp;useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8/>"
```

Tomcat2

```
<Resource name="jdbc/monitor" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100"
maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="user" password="password" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/monitorbeta 
autoReconnect=true&amp;useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8/>"
```

Calling to Initial context in the code (in all servlets on both servers) is made in a very standart way:

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/monitor");
Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();            
return connection;
```

Problem is that on Tomcat2 one of the servlets gets the connction from Tomcat1 context.xml (and therefore updates the wrong tables) - while other servlet 'goes' to the right context!!
I restarted the services, made sure that Tomcats use other ports and that catalina home/base are set right on Tomcat2. What do I miss?

EDIT:
Also, I was trying to set manually the enviorment to InitialContext like this:

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"rmi://localhost:9080");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

still, no success

Comment: Have you configured your Tomcat2 Initialcontext to lookup the naming provider at the new port number?  Otherwise it'll use the default port number, which here is the one running on Tomcat1.  YOu can set it through the `java.naming.provider.url` property.

Comment: @AlexanderLanger do you mean add -d java.naming.provider.url = //localhost:XXXX to java options?

Comment: No, you would pass these options to your `InitialContext`, see, e.g., http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#InitialContext(java.util.Hashtable)

Comment: @AlexanderLanger look at my edit, still pointing at the wrong context

Comment: port 9080 looks unfamiliar, the default port is 1099; of course for the tomcat2 instance you'd have to specify the port number you did in the tomcat2 server configuration, which must be different from the tomcat1 port number.  Did you try that?

Comment: @AlexanderLanger Sorry, you must be right, my Tomcat-fu is weak. port 1099 isn't one of the default ports defined in server.xml I couldnt find how to change it in the net, and no one answered new question I've opened. can you help out?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I'm not using Tomcat by myself.  However, I'm pretty sure that's the reason why your Tomcat2 instance connects to your Tomcat1-Datasource, because it does do the JNDI lookup with Tomcat1's naming provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with my JDBC handler, It explicitly overrun the Initial context definitions...